# How can I get a date object in LaTeX?

Tags: programming, datetime

I want a date object I can just sprinkle throughout my document at any moment. For example, I might type "Today (\date) happens to be quite nice."

Comment: Have you tried using `\today`? More seriously, what do you mean by "date object". For example, is `\newcommand{\halloween}{Oct 31}` a "date object"?

Comment: I'm just using the language ingrained in my background in python, C++, perl, bla bla bla. `\today` seems like an object, does it not?

Comment: I'm looking at Method 1 here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74973/how-to-add-barely-visible-tracking-dots-to-a-b-w-document I would like to do `\setgrid[5][.3]{\today}`, and I'm about to find out if it works.

Comment: @CucumberFace LaTeX2e is not really what you would call "object-oriented"...

Comment: I could care less. Is \today an object or not to you? Answer me that. I'm curious.

Comment: Also, I disagree. I feel that with sufficient creativity it could be object-oriented. Perhaps this should be a discussion in its own right.

Comment: Well, you can't really reason in terms of "objects" in LaTeX (2e, at least). All you have is "macros", i.e. things that expand to other stuff that may or may not perform actions.

Comment: The idea of what might be termed "modular object methodology" seems inherent to certain aspects of LaTeX. Would you agree?

Comment: If the formatting of `\today` should be changed, see [Date format in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31137/5764).

Comment: You are reading my mind... Weird... I assume that \theday instead of \THEDAY will give Mon as opposed to Monday, correct?

Comment: @CucumberFace Can we close your question as a duplicate of that linked by Werner in his comment?

Comment: By all means. Got to save space on the server.